# How to select multiple columns from a detail table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have the following tables:

- `MASTER` table (ID(PK), NAME, etc)
- `DETAIL` table (ID(PK), IDMASTER(FK), VALUE1, DATE1, etc)

What I need is a SQL query or a way to do a select like

I work with SQL Server.

What I need is a SQL query or a way to do a select like

```
SELECT 
    M.ID, M.NAME,
    (SELECT TOP 1 DT.ID, DT.VALUE1 
     FROM DETAIL D 
     WHERE D.IDMASTER = M.ID 
     ORDER BY DATE 1 DESC)
    -- more than one column with a where clause and an order clause
FROM 
    MASTER M
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT  M.ID, 
        M.NAME
        D.ID,
        D.VALUE1
FROM dbo.[MASTER] M
OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 ID, VALUE1
            FROM dbo.DETAIL
            WHERE IDMASTER = M.ID
            ORDER BY [DATE] DESC) D;
```

Answer (score 0):

You do this with `APPLY` operator:

```
select * from master m
outer apply(select top 1 * from detail d where d.masterid = m.id order by d.date1 desc)oa
```